# Подгрузка JSON при клике по ссылке

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Здравствуйте! Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку подгружался файл JSON. При проверке через консоль без события Click все работает:

```
    $.getJSON('serv.json', function (serv) {
    console.log(serv);
     });
    });
```

Но когда добавляю событие на клик - ничего  не происходит:

```
    $('#virtual').click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $.getJSON('serv.json', function (serv) {
    console.log(serv);
     });
    });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. HTML-код для ссылки:

```
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden-xs" id="virtual">
    <img src="images/virtualna_dovidka.png" class="img">
    <a href="#"> Довідка</a></div>
```

Comment: кстати, зачем вам ссылка, которая никуда не ведет?

Comment: В дальнейшем мне нужно,чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку (соответственно там будет уже адрес),происходил переход к нужному диву,в который и будет подгружаться файл JSON) но пока что этот JSON даже в консоли не отображается

Comment: у Вас есть какой-нибудь обработчик клика на тэге `а`?

Comment: нет обработчика

Comment: @Yaroslava какой-нибудь родитель у `virtual` имеется? этот блок не динамически подгружается случаем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

```
$('#virtual a').click(function () {
"use strict";
  $.getJSON('serv.json', function (serv) {
    console.log(serv);
  });
  return false;
});
```

Но должно работать и так:

```js
$('#virtual').click(function() {
  "use strict";
  console.log("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hidden-xs" id="virtual">
  <img src="images/virtualna_dovidka.png" class="img">
  <a href="#"> Довідка</a>
</div>
```

Comment: все равно не работает..ни одним из способов( не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: @Yaroslava Уберите вызов `$.getJSON` и оставьте только `console.log("test");`. `"test"` появляется в консоли?

Comment: не появляется..

Comment: @Yaroslava Ну вот. С этим и надо разбираться. Заверните этот код в `$(document).ready(function{...});`.

Comment: даааа) заработало)

Comment: @Yaroslava Рад за Вас. Раньше Ваш код выполнялся до создания элементов DOM-a, и обработчик ни к чему не прикреплялся.

Comment: Теперь понятно) спасибо большое)

Comment: @Yaroslava На здоровье. "Галочка" слева - щелк :).